# How to show another layout when login successful

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android, I have two questions.

1. I want to show another layout when login successful.
2. else part not working in `onsuccess()` method. If the user gives wrong username and password means throw error message, however I get error:

   `application stopped unfortunately`

Here is my code:

**LoginFragment.java**

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {

                // Hide Progress Dialog

                prgDialog.hide();
                try {
                    // JSON Object
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response));
                    // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true
                    if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You are successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Navigate to Home screen
                        navigatetoSearchActivity();
                    }
                    // Else display error message
                    else {
                        errorMsg.setText(obj.getString("error_msg"));
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }


            // When the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responsebody, Throwable error) {
                // Hide Progress Dialog
                prgDialog.hide();
                // When Http response code is '404'
                if (statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // When Http response code is '500'
                else if (statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Method which navigates from Login Activity to Search Activity
     */
    public void navigatetoSearchActivity(){
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Search.class);
        //searchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(searchIntent);
    }
```

**Search.java**

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Search extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Displays Search Screen
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
    }
}
```

**First question logcat:**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.h2o/com.h2o.Search}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onUserException(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:313)
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:404)
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.h2o/com.h2o.Search}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:829)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:897)
            at com.h2o.LoginFragment$TabsAdapter.navigatetoSearchActivity(LoginFragment.java:278)
            at com.h2o.LoginFragment$TabsAdapter$3.onSuccess(LoginFragment.java:235)
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:360)
            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**Second question logcat:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onUserException(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:313)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:404)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.h2o.LoginFragment$TabsAdapter$3.onSuccess(LoginFragment.java:239)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:360)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: That's not the error. Copy your logcat here.

Comment: @Razul have you considered marking answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Errors are clearly shown in logcat provided.
1) Activity is not declared in Manifest. Declare it in activity tag.
2) You are setting text on a text view without initialising it.

eg : `TextView tv=(TextView)fingViewById(R.id.tv1);`

Answer (score 2):

**For first question**

Add an entry to your manifest for `search activity`.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.packagename.yourMainActivityName" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**For second question:**
Check the following points that could solve your problem:

> 1.Check if your response is null or not.
>
> 2.The error can be the `JSONobject` from which you are fetching `status` check whether your `obj` is null or not.
>
> 3.Check whether you have declare and initialise your `errorMsg` textview.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this `<activity android:name="com.h2o.Search" ></activity>` in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.stockquote.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.h2o.Search" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please declare the search class in the manifest file of your project.

Sample:

```
<activity android:name=".Search">   </activity>
```

Comment: @Appu Perhaps consider accepting one of the provided answers? It is the way to say "thanks" here :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question it seems like you wish to start a new activity with a new layout. Please read the [Google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), it is very helpful on the topic (By adding the activity with your IDE you do not have to edit the manifest file yourself, as other answers guide you to).

For the second question it seems your errorMsg is not initialized. You need something along

```
errorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorMessageId);
```

The `findViewById()` is method of the `Activity` class, so you might need to fetch it with `getActivity()`.